# Server settings to improved Wordpress backend speed

Tags: php, web-server, performance, wordpress

You know how it is, caching plugins only make the front-end move faster but when you're logged in and browsing the wp-admin section, the Wordpress site grinds to a halt. I'm trying to increase some backend speed of my Wordpress site and would like to know what are the best PHP and server settings to get the speed improved.

Currently my settings are as follows:

- **PHP Version:** 7.4
- **PHP Memory Limit:** 512mb (Should I add more?)
- **PHP Time Limit:** 300 (Should I add more?)
- **PHP Max Input Vars:** 2500 (What's a good number here?)
- **Web Server:** Apache with NGINX proxy

Does Redis or Varnish do anything for the backend?

Answer (score 1):

Memory limit and time limit do not affect speed, neithed does PHP Max Input Vars.

Best option for speeding up backend is to use a proper caching plugin which caches database queries, provides a memory-based store for Object caching and transients.

This will reduce the need to make calls to database, which will speed up operation.

Most caching plugins actually have an effect on backend too, because they implement caching in the levels I mentioned above. Caching plugins that create static HTML files of the site do not affect backend operation.

Otherwise, the question is far too generic to give any specific optimization advice. It all depends on the hosting setup, what kind of plugins are used etc.